# Why is water diamagnetic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, physical-chemistry, molecules

I checked using my permanent magnet that water is [diamagnetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamagnetism). But *why* is it like that? Does this have any important consequence for life?

Comment: Many of the answers here are pretty simplified and are based on empirical rules. The  full answer would need to take into account Zeeman and Langevin magnetic effects and check what is winning and why. This calculation is not always easy and sometimes it is not as simple as to say that a particular shell is filled.

Answer (score 2):

Diamagnetism is often explained in terms of the fact that water has two paired electrons in their hybridised orbitals according to Valence Bond Theory. This is partially correct as we know that Valence Bond Theory is not the correct measure of magnetism.

The more correct theory to explain this is Molecular Orbital Theory which states that water is diamagnetic as its Molecular Orbitals have paired electrons.

Comment: But  MOT shows water is paramagnetic.Till $\sigma$ *2s, 8 electrons are filled. The remaining 2 electrons should go in $\pi 2p_x$ and $\pi 2p_y$ equally(since both have equal energy). So both molecular orbitals will be half filled.

Comment: @Jdeep Search for MO diagram of water. I think you are mistakenly using a symmetrical diatomic compound's MO diagram for water (unsymmetrical triatomic compound).

Answer (score -4):

Compounds having even number of total electrons will be diamagnetic 
10 and 16 are exceptions 
They Will be paramagnetic
[image]

Comment: it would be much better if you could typeset your answer.

Comment: Iron: 26 electrons so ferromagnetic.

Comment: Water has 10 electrons not 18. So by your above statement water should be **paramagnetic**